# Draw a multipolygon

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I need to build a shutter like this:

[image: picture of a shutter]

What is the formulas to draw each vertex?

Suppose I have `num` which is the number of triangles (in this case `num=7`) and the radius of the circle. How can I obtain the coordinates of each vertex of each triangle of the shutter?

I don't know how to obtain these coordinates.

Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe you can start by considering the edges of the outer $n$-gon (7-gon, in the picture) and think about the coordinates of those edge points ...

Comment: @MattiP. I need the coordinates of each triangle beacuse I need to consider each triangle individually. So, I'm not looking for a formula to draw the entire shutter but a formula to draw each triangle of the shutter.

Comment: Once you know the coordinates of all vertices you can draw each triangle and also draw the entire shutter: there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the name $n$ instead of `num` for the number of triangles because it works better in math formulas. You can translate back when using it in your software.

In the "shutter" we can see an outer $n$-gon (containing all the rest of the figure)
and an inner $n$-gon (the white or empty region in the middle).
The inner $n$-gon is smaller than the outer $n$-gon and is rotated so that each edge of the inner $n$-gon, extended in a clockwise direction relative to the center of the $n$-gon, intersects a vertex of the outer $n$-gon.

The regions bounded by these extended edges and the edges of the outer $n$-gon are the triangles you want to draw.

One edge of a triangle is simply one of the edges of the outer $n$-gon,
which is easy enough to plot.
Assuming you are using standard Cartesian coordinates
(perpendicular $x$ and $y$ axes, and the positive $y$ axis is counterclockwise from the positive $x$ axis),
if the center of the shutter is to be at the point $O = (x_0,y_0),$
you can plot the vertices of side $k$ of the $n$-gon at
$$ A = \left(x_0 + R\cos\left(\theta_0 + \frac{2\pi}n k\right),
         y_0 + R\sin\left(\theta_0 + \frac{2\pi}n k\right)\right) $$
and
$$ B = \left(x_0 + R\cos\left(\theta_0 + \frac{2\pi}n (k + 1)\right),
         y_0 + R\sin\left(\theta_0 + \frac{2\pi}n (k + 1)\right)\right), $$
where $\theta_0$ is an angle that determines how the entire shutter is oriented relative to your drawing; increasing $\theta_0$ will rotate the entire shutter counterclockwise.

Now let $M$ be the midpoint of the segment $AB.$
Then $\triangle OMA$ is a right triangle with its right angle at $M.$
The hypotenuse $OA$ has length $R$ and the angle at $O$ is $\pi/n,$
so $OM = R \cos(\pi/n).$

If $C$ is the third vertex of the triangle that you want to draw adjacent edge $AB,$
if $D$ is the vertex of the inner $n$-gon between $A$ and $C,$ and if $P$ is the midpoint of $CD,$ then $\triangle OPA$ is a right triangle with its right angle at $P,$ again with hypotenuse $OA.$

The next part depends on how you want to set the inner shape of the shutter.
You can specify the angle $\alpha$ at $A$ in the triangle $\triangle ABC,$
you can specify the distance from the center to one of the vertices of the inner $n$-gon (that is, specify the length $OC$), 
or you can specify the distance from the center to the midpoint of a side of the inner $n$-gon (that is, specify the length $OP$).

Any one of these measurements gives you the other two.
When we know either $OC$ or $OP,$ we can derive the other value using the formula
$$ OP = OC \cos(\pi/n). $$
When we know either $\alpha$ or $OP$ we can derive the other value from the formula
$$ OP = R \cos\left(\frac\pi n + \alpha\right), $$
because $\angle POM = \alpha.$

So let's suppose you specified the inner shape of the shutter somehow and that you now have the values of $\alpha$ and $OC.$ Then the coordinates of $C$ are obtained by a  formula similar to the one for $B,$ but scaled down (because it is a vertex of a smaller $n$-gon) and rotated by the angle $\alpha$:
$$ C = \left(x_0 + OC\cos\left(\theta_0 + \frac{2\pi}n (k + 1) + \alpha\right),
         y_0 + OC\sin\left(\theta_0 + \frac{2\pi}n (k + 1) + \alpha\right)\right). $$

If you would like to know the sides and angles of triangle $\triangle ABC,$
they are
\begin{align}
AB &= 2R \sin\left(\frac\pi n\right), \\
AC &= R \left(\sin\left(\frac\pi n + \alpha\right) 
  + \sin\left(\frac\pi n\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi n + \alpha\right)\right),\\
BC &= R \left(\sin\left(\frac\pi n + \alpha\right) 
  - \sin\left(\frac\pi n\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi n + \alpha\right)\right),\\
\angle BAC &= \alpha, \\
\angle ACB &= \frac{2\pi}n, \\
\angle ABC &= \pi - \frac{2\pi}n - \alpha.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta), \theta = \frac{360i + offset}{num}$$

Where $i = 0,...,num-1$, and offset can 'rotate' the starting point.
Look up polar coordinates or circle parametric equation.

Comment: I need the coordinates of each triangle because I need to consider each triangle individually. So, I'm not looking for a formula to draw the entire shutter but a formula to draw each triangle of the shutter.

Comment: What I wrote solves your problem. You have 1 bigger n-gon with n vertices and one smaller inside with also n vertices. Let the bigger polygon's vertices be $p_1,...,p_n$ and the inner one be $q_1,...,q_n$, then form tris $(p_1,p_2,q_1), (p_2, p_3, q_2), ..., (p_n, p_1, q_n)$, set different offset and radius for p and q and you are done.